# How to open a browser window through Word using VBA with set height, width, and no menu bar

Tags: vba, ms-word

I basically want to open a browser window from Word using VBA that does the same as javascipt:

```
window.open ("http://www.google.com","mywindow","menubar=0,resizable=0,width=350,height=250");
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You can set the target property of a hyperlink, for example _blank but that's about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like:

```
Sub window_Open(strLocation As String, Menubar As Boolean, height As Long, width As Long, resizable As Boolean)

With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    .Visible = False
    .height = height
    .width = width
    .Menubar = Menubar
    .Visible = True
    .resizable = resizable
    .Navigate strLocation
End With


End Sub

Sub test()
window_Open "www.google.com", True, 250, 350, False
End Sub
```